# Mac doesn't detect CD-ROM properly

Tags: macbook-pro, finder, disk-utility, optical-drive, cd-burning

I have a `CD-ROM 700 MB, 80 Minute Recordable Disc` that I want to burn a video on, and with some help I've found Burn and DVDStyler. However, both do not recognise my CD-R. 
When I enter the CD-ROM, a menu pops up asking me what I want to do, and if I select "Open with finder", nothing happens. The drive stops sounding busy after some time.

Finder only recognises my external remote disc drive, and the info is suspiciously empty. Disc Utility, on the other hand, does seem to identify the CD-ROM correctly as `HL-DT-ST DVDRW GX40N Media`, but it is uninitialised and unwritable. Is there anything I can do in order to get Burn or DVDStyler to recognise my CD-ROM and burn data on it?

[image]

Comment: When you say you want to burn a video, what exactly do you mean? Are you wanting to just *copy* the file onto the disc, or are you wanting the disc to behave like a DVD? Also, forgive the obvious question, but have you double-checked to ensure there is no data already on the disc? Finally, and this is one of the most frustrating things about optical media, have you tried another brand of media? Sometimes for unknown reasons media can be *incompatible* with optical devices.

Comment: @Monomeeth I'm trying to burn a video to make the disc behave like a DVD. I had a bunch of them lying around somewhere from a few years back :), but as the package was unopened so far I assume that they must be empty. I haven't tried another brand. Tbh, I have absolutely no idea about optical devices whatsoever, except that usually DVDs work on my mac/external remote disc drive.

Comment: Load the disk: open Disk Utility, select the disk, then click the 'Erase' tab. Choose the format you require.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I can't. Erase (and all other menu options) are greyed out.

Comment: Don't "Erase" a CD-R. They're write-once; that will effectively kill it. A CD-R won't be seen by the Finder, only by burning software, as there's nothing beforehand to 'see'. That it is being seen as CD ROM not CD-R is the potentially worrying part. CD-R would be 'ready to write', CD ROM would be 'already written'.

Comment: WHICH MAC IS IT SPECIFICALLY, THE MODEL

Comment: The HL-DT-ST DVDRW GX40N is your disk drive (not the disk) and Apple has offered some firmware updates for it https://support.apple.com/downloads/SuperDrive_Firmware_Update_3_0

Comment: @Buscar MacBookPro, Late 2013, Retina 15‘. Running the latest version of Mojave.

Comment: However @Tetsujin might be right. Currently your Mac says those are CDROM only (Read Only Memory) not RW (Read Write) check the label on the disk ?

Comment: It says CDROM 80 Minute Recordable Disc. What's the point of buying those (definitely empty) if I can't write them at least once?!

Comment: ok...ok.. I was just asking, for some reason your Mac does not think so. Does it show in Finder-side window. Did you look at the disk burning app called Toast DVD ?